# Freeze system time

Tags: android, adb

Does anybody know how can I freeze (stop) Android's system time?

For example, I set system time to `00:00:00` and I want the time to not advance.

I can change time by adb shell date, and I made a script with `while(1)`, but because I test some program there are some delays, I can't set true time.

Comment: why would you want to do that? And post what you've tried so far please.

Comment: I edited the question to try to make the English clearer, but I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say at the end. What do you mean by "because I test some program there is some delays, I can't set true time"? Do you mean that because you're running another program that competes for CPU time, the infinite loop doesn't execute fast enough to hold the time at 00:00:00, and it occasionally advances by a second or two before going back to all zeros? Please clarify.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I think he did post what he tried. He tried using an infinite loop that keeps resetting the time to whatever he wants to freeze it at.

Comment: Adi Inbar, "the infinite loop doesn't execute fast enough to hold the time at 00:00:00" yes, you're right. I can't cache the system time in static variable, program is black box for me :) Thx, for editing :) Program take system time, make some operations and give me result, I need hold the system time at 00:00:00.000 and take  result. Infinity loop not fast and it has milliseconds fluctuations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're asking is possible. Just cache the system time in your own static instance variable and then reference that in your application.